# Should I accept the same object as a parameter and return it or just accept it as a parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following interface:

```
public IStateMachineConfigurator
{
  ??? Configure(StateMachine machine);
}
```

In the implementation I am calling some of the StateMachine methods to configure it like this:

```
machine.Configure(States.State1)
       .Allow(Triggers.Trigger1);
```

The question is, can I rely on the fact that the StateMachine object is a reference or should I use a return value or a return parameter like ref/out?

EDIT:
The state machine itself comes from a library and thus I cannot decide it's implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on the fact that `StateMachine` is an object reference. Some people might choose to return a `bool` or perhaps an `enum` to give the programmer some kind of hint as to what happened in the `Configure` method (ie. success/fail/no change/etc.). Others might choose to throw an exception in the event something goes wrong.

All are perfectly valid, just be careful how deep you chain the method together, as something like:

`machine.Configure().Allow().someMethod().someOtherMethod()`

Gets difficult to debug and trace.

Comment: That's why I am hiding it and allowing to configure from an external component.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna go with the builder pattern then your effectivly return the mutable state that is being passed in. This is perfectly fine, if you wanna go down that road. This is how the StringBuilder class operates and on a somewhat different note jQuery. It can be very nice for building objects in a compact and readable fashion. However, those objects should be designated as such. Builder objects and preferably not take on more than necessary.

Comment: The state machine already uses the builder pattern. I would like to introduce a class that will configure everything that the state machine needs.

Comment: The StateMachine 'tis a class, 'tis it not? Then you should be all set.

Comment: The purpose of the Configurator is to inject a class that will configure the allowed states and triggers. I don't have control over the state machine implementation. It is a library.

Comment: Then it depends on what the StateMachine object is. My guess would be that it's fine if you wanna return the reference to continue using the builder patten as shown there by your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `Configurator`, I would rather craete a `Configuration` object and pass it in the `StateMachine` constructor. This makes it cleare to the users of `StateMachine` class that they have to provide it with a valid configuration before using it.

```
class StateMachineConfiguration
{
    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Trigger> Triggers { get; private set; }
}

class StateMachine
{
    public StateMachine(StateMachineConfiguration config) 
    {
         if(config == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException();

         this.Configure(config.States);
         this.Allow(config.Triggers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the state machine implementation. It's a library.